# HTML Table column width practices

Tags: html, html-table, width

What are good practices when selecting column widths in a table?
Let's say I have four columns, name (variable width), description (long content of text), count (max 3 chars), date (fixed format).

What would be a good practice? I'm thinking fixed width for descr., count and width (thus actually also making name "fixed" width).
But my real question is, how to select a particular width size.
For instance, if the date format is yyyy-MM-dd is there some trick to convert those 10 chars to a width which will guarantee that it shows ok in any browser using any font and font-size (without also taking up any excessive space)?

edit: With fixed I mean something akin to "fixed amount of pixels relative to font width"

Comment: You could use em as the unit of measure, this would guarantee that you will have enough space, but would probably provide you with more than you'd need.

Comment: I am thinking fixed amount of pixels relative to font width means em, as Kevin Wiskia has commented, but I personally find fixing the pixels a bad idea (when it comes to width - it is good for height though). The reason being that you do not know the width of the users screen. Lets suppose your table only needs 500 pixels, but the user has a 1920 by 1080 screen. This means that your table is now taking up just under 25% of the screen width. However with my method you can take up, say, 75% of the screen and have each column as a certain percentage of that 75%.

Comment: @ClarkeyBoy, Good point. Perhaps then a good solution would be to specify table width to 75% and the individual columns/cells using white-space: nowrap with font size in em?
Then the columns would take up exactly as much space as needed (no excessive space) and it wouldn't look tiny even in 1920x1080.

Comment: @ClarkeyBoy - You are assuming that the layout itself would take 100% of the screen width. Plus, if the table only *needs* 500px, but you're forcing it to stretch to almost 4 times that, a lot of unnecessary space would be added between columns, making rows very hard to follow, unless some sort of row highlighting is implemented.

Comment: @FreekOne: The most common layout technique is to use percentages. I am assuming that icanBany1 is using this layout technique in my answer - but thought I should point out the disadvantage of using fixed widths just in case. I have produced a couple of sites and prefer to have a div of width 50 or 60%, centred, and then content within this doesnt look too big or small whatever size screen it is. Anywho I am getting a bit distracted by X Factor right now so I dont know if what I have written makes sense. I will post another comment if I havent made my point or think of anything else to say.

Comment: @ClarkeyBoy fair enough. I wasn't disagreeing, but rather pointing the possible pitfalls in user friendliness.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can declare `white-space: nowrap;` on all the cells that you want to stretch as much as they need without using extra space (name, date, count), and then simply give your remaining cell a width of 100%. This way the 100% wide cell will expand as much as possible, without causing the other cells to collapse on multiple lines.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to save yourself lots of markup...

First, if by fixed width you mean a fixed percentage, add the following to your stylesheet:

```
.width1 {
    width: 1%;
}
.width2 {
    width: 2%;
}
.width99 {
    width: 99%;
}
.width100 {
    width: 100%;
}
```

This gives you the flexibility you need if you decide to apply an odd percentage width for any of them if you wish - for example width23 on one of them, width 27 on another.

Now this is the clever bit. Using the `col` tag, you can apply widths just once instead of on every cell. I know you can apply widths to just the first row, and they will set the widths for the same cell in every other row - but the `col` tag can be used for setting other properties too. For example:

```
<table class="width100">
    <col class="width15" style="background-color: #cccccc;" />
    <col class="width65" />
    <col class="width10" />
    <col class="width10" />
    <tr>
        <td>My Sample Name</td>
        <td>My Sample Long Description</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>2010-Oct-08</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I generally prefer to use this technique - but if it is a layout I will be using on multiple tables (for example the customers table may be the same layout as the agents table) then I will create a class for each column and set the width etc in that class. I will then apply the relevant class to each cell. I suppose both methods could be combined - the relevant class could be applied to the relevant col, but the fact that the properties are set in one place (the stylesheet) means that you only have to change it in once place.

Hope this helps and that it is what you are looking for.

Richard

Comment: Whats with the downvote? Its perfectly relevant to the question and is a very quick solution... I wish it was compulsory for people to say WHY they downvoted...

Comment: Probably because it adds a lot of superfluous code to your CSS that needs to be transferred to the client. It's unsemantic. And the <col> tag doesn't work 100%.

Comment: But it hardly affects the speed to load the page though - I personally dont particularly care how much code my sites have to download - if I can load them fast on my computer (with maximum broadband speed of 50kb per second) then near enough anyone can. If it loads fast on my machine then I am happy.

Comment: Perhaps I should have been more clear on what I meant by fixed width. I'll update the question. Thanks for your reply though, could come in handy some day :)

Comment: Downvoted because it's not semantic. CSS class names should identify classes of elements on the page, not scalar values to be applied within the styling.

Comment: Just because the name has a scalar value which just happens to be applied to properties therein, doesn't mean the name isn't 'semantic' .. `width100` could be `widthFull` and doesn't change anything. Following your creed ad infinitum/nauseam, you'll wind up with numerous classes with the exact same properties because you 'semantically' _shouldn't_ consider a class for divs with `width: 2px;` the same as an identical class for tds.. It's always a blend & tradeoff; nothing is absolute. Sure, you don't want to change width to 40 but the name say 20.. But that's just developer laziness.

Comment: @MatthewTaylor Tailwind CSS and Bootstrap 4 seem to have gone against your recommendation - which is now considered "best practice". Class utilities are now the norm.