# HTML Tables: Is there a good practice for specifying column widths?

Tags: html, css

I would like to tweak a few tables in order to get the best possible presentation of my interface. Is there a good practice way to specify the widths of table columns? (e.g. If I want to display the first column as 100px wide, the second as 80px wide and the third as 60px wide.)

I took a look at [HTML Table column width practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3892409/html-table-column-width-practices) however the selected answer (while useful for the user asking the question) did not describe how this could be done.

Another answer to that question suggested using `<col>` to assign a class to each column and then determine the width in CSS. However, this seems inelegant and a commenter suggests issues with the `<col>` tag. Also, I believe it has been deprecated in HTML5?

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <col class=width100>
    <col class=width80>
    <col class=width60> 
    <tr>
        <th>Column 1</th> 
        <th>Column 2</th>
        <th>Column 3</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
width100 {
    width: 100px; 
}

width80 {
    width: 80px; 
}

width60 {
    width: 60px; 
}
```

This seems rather inelegant, and I am unsure over the reliability / deprecation of the `<col>` tag. Is there a better way?

Comment: Why not just put the class straight onto the cell?

Comment: While I could do that for the first row of cells, I was not sure if doing so is an advisable solution. I am not even sure if giving `<col>`s or `<th>`s a class such as `width100` etc. is good practice. There are several ways this *could* be solved (though, apologies, I should have included this as an alternative beside the first example) however I would like to find a solution that is good practice, if possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I will split your question into two parts and answer the second part first:

> **Part 2**: However, this seems inelegant and a commenter suggests issues
>   with the  tag. Also, I believe it has been deprecated in HTML5?

No. It has **not** been deprecated in HTML5. In fact, `colgroup` and `col` together are very important elements as part of the table.

e.g. have a look at this ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/col

> ...defines a column within a table and is used for defining common
>   semantics on all common cells...

Further down it says:

> CSS properties and pseudo-classes that may be specially useful to
>   style the  element: the width property to control the width of
>   the column;...

Going by this ref: http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html-markup-20120329/col.html#col

> The width attribute on the col element is obsolete. Use CSS instead

To summarize, you would be better off using `colgroup` and/or `col` to layout your tables. They help you to define common semantics on all corresponding cells. CSS is the recommended method to apply widths, which helps keep the presentation of the table separate from the markup. Using `colgroup` and/or `col` will actually save you a lot of trouble and gives you greater control on your table(s).

> **Part 1**: Is there a good practice way to specify the widths of table
>   columns? (e.g. If I want to display the first column as 100px wide,
>   the second as 80px wide and the third as 60px wide.)

Again, if you refer to the docs you will find that delegating widths to CSS via `col` is a good practice to follow. Ideally, you would want to use a consistent unit for widths for your entire app/website. If you are using a fluid layout having percentages, then it makes perfect sense to keep percent units for your tables as well. If you are designing for a pixel-grid layout, then pixels would be better fit for your tables.

Delegating the presentation part to CSS will also help you in implementing a responsive layout if required.

**Edit**:

Regarding the issue you describe of people saying CSS class names should necessarily *"identify classes of elements on the page, not scalar values to be applied within the styling"* and that it is not semantic and all that stuff:

I don't personally agree to that.

IMO: See this: (http://getbootstrap.com/css) as an example. Although bootstrap is not using widths (verbatim) in names, but it does use metrics as part of class names. e.g. `col-xs-6` (a column which is extra small spanning 4 columns). By all means, name your classes in a way which suits you and is easy to understand. Go ahead, create your own naming convention.

Comment: Thank you. Do you suggest using the `width100` style classes as per the example in the linked question?

Comment: Why not? I do not agree with those comments. See this: http://getbootstrap.com/css/ as an example. Although bootstrap is not using widths (verbatim) in names, but it does use metrics as part of class names. e.g.`col-xs-6` (a column which is extra small spanning 4 columns). By all means, name your classes  in a way which suits you and is easy to understand. Go ahead, create your own naming convention.

Comment: I just wanted to clarify :) Thank you!

Comment: @Eilidh: added that to the answer.

Comment: In this case I suggest using names like "col1", "col2", ... for the css classes rather than width100. What if the design changes and you decide to have width 200px for first column? You will have to not only update css, also class names to avoid confusion. In bootstrap class names example, those classes are meant to be used anywhere in applications, knowing that they will make xs columns spanning 4. It is their "identity". But in this case, the class is literally meant for that column, and is better be bound to that column name. In this case the column position in that table is the "identity".

Answer (score 1):

To avoid repeating the class in each td element, you could try using pseudo classes to select the nth td in your table.

Something like this:

```
td:nth-child(1){
    color: red;
    width: 100px;
}
td:nth-child(2) {
    color: blue;
    width: 80px;
}
td:nth-child(3) {
    color: green;
    width: 60px;
}
```

To cover table header cells:

```
th:nth-child(1){
    color: red;
    width: 100px;
}
th:nth-child(2) {
    color: blue;
    width: 80px;
}
th:nth-child(3) {
    color: green;
    width: 60px;
}
```

More info on `:nth-child` (and pseudo classes) here: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-child)

Comment: Cheers! I use pseudo-classes to do the typical alternating row background colour trick, but it hadn't occured to me to do it for this. 

One issue, though - not all of my tables are structured with a row of `<th>`s at the top. Some are simply one row of `<th><td><th><td>` etc. - how would I account for this? 

Thank you!

Comment: I've just added a set of th styles, and it seems to work.  I haven't gone on a proper cross-browser test though, so it's possible there will be fish hooks somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It's bad practice to add columns, we can give width directly th or adding specific class, no need to add new more code for col.

[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/AmDfI)